# Change field in MySQL from TEXT to LONGTEXT

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is probably very easy, but I have googled and not found or understood how to do this. May be because I really don't know what to search after. Have searched after "change field type from TEXT to LONGTEXT" etc.

I have a table named "setting" and inside there a "row" where the first value ("column") is "setting_id".

I would like to edit the field value from being TEXT to use LONGTEXT.

I have googled and searched here, but not find the answer. I have found solutions to change a column from using TEXT to LONGTEXT. But I think that is the wrong answer. But I don't know.

This is how it looks like in the phpMyAdmin. (See image) The field "value" needs to be using LONGTEXT as the content is really long and does not fit in TEXT.

How do I do this? - I really appreciate you helping me out here.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply go to table structure and change field type from `TEXT` to `LONGTEXT`.

Or you can do it with this sql:

```
ALTER TABLE `setting` MODIFY `value` LONGTEXT
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought there was a way to only edit the row's field, but I understand now that I need to do it for the whole table column. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you run an SQL query instead?

```
ALTER TABLE setting MODIFY value LONGTEXT;
```

Comment: `setting_id` should be `int(11)`. OP needs to change `value`.

Comment: Oh my god, the question was so misleading... Fixed.

Comment: Sorry if the question was misleading. I am not sure what the correct words for this case is. Am a bit confused as to what the different fields etc are named. 

I run the above SQL query, and it updated all fields to LONGTEXT. Probably the correct way to do it then? Thank you.

Comment: In your question you were speaking about unrelated things like the setting_id field which appears as the first one, for instance. What you wanted is just to change the type of the field called "value" from "TEXT" to "LONGTEXT", that's it. I got confused because you used the word "value" to refer to "column", and then you used it to refer to a field called "value".

Comment: I see. English is not my first language, so that might be the reason. Sorry for the confusion  :-) I thought I could set the LONGTEXT for only "html_everwhere" and not needed to do that for the whole table. It's just for the "html_everywhere" I needed it.